# Windows 8 app: How to pass a parameter on GoBack()?

Tags: windows-8, navigation, windows-runtime

There are a lot of samples showing how to pass a parameter on navigating to a page in Window 8 (WinRT). But I could not find any hint for passing parameters going back. 
Situation: The user navigates to a details page of same data. The data is passed to the page by

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(DedtailsPage), data);
```

How can I pass back the changed data on `GoBack()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the reference to data somewhere and retrieve it when you navigate back?

Also note that it's best not to pass objects other than simple strings or values between pages, since only simple types are supported for storing frame navigation state in case your app gets suspended.

Answer (score 2):

I know, that this is a very bad idea, but usualy I use this:

1. To write:

   Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

   rootFrame.Tag = myObject1;
2. To read:

   Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

   var myObject2 = rootFrame.Tag;

Answer (score 0):

I've made another choice to handle this.
Keep in mind that I'm a Xamarin developer (not Forms!) so i was looking for a solution which was similar for all platforms: iOS, Android and Windows.

I am a great fun of events, rather than passing objects or storing globals.
So the best choice to pass data from PageB (the child) to PageA (the parent) is to communicate via events.

Some notes: In iOS and Android, when you navigate from a "page" to "page" you can do this by passing an instance of the target object you want to navigate to. In iOS you create an instance of a custom UIViewController. In Android you create an instance of a custom Fragment. Doing this allow you to attach events handler to your instances.

An example:

```
var controller = new ExtrasViewController();
controller.ExtraSelected += ExtrasFragment_ExtraSelected;
controller.ExtrasCleared += ExtrasFragment_ExtrasCleared;
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, false);
```

In WinRT Apps you are only allowed to pass "types" of target page to navigate to. So the only way to attach event handlers to your page instance is to use the OnNavigatedFrom method from the calling page. So suppose you are in PageA and want to attach some event handlers to your PageB, before it become active, simply write in your PageA "code behind":

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

    var page = e.Content as ExtraBody;
    if(page != null)
    {
        page.ExtraSelected += ExtrasFragment_ExtraSelected;
        page.ExtrasCleared += ExtrasFragment_ExtrasCleared;
    }
}
```